# Programming language to use with MySQL: Java or C++?

Tags: java, php, c++, mysql

I don't know much of either languages, but what would be better for writing applications that deals with the following. Right now, I use PHP, but I'm looking to see what would be the next ideal language to dig into, if the needs arise.

- MySQL
- off-line data processing of CSV, XML, etc. files
- web applications (dynamic websites)

I understand that this could quite possibly be subjective.. so if you could just pitch in some pros and cons, that would be superb. TIA!

Comment: Per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."  I'm not sure if your question qualifies. Maybe it would be better off on [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Choose the language you know the best.  I am currently using both, on separate applications.  The Java langauge comes with GUI support whereas C++ requires a GUI framework.  I got the Java application working faster than the C++ version.  Although I am using C++ for the heavier-weight application and Java for the light-weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you come from PHP, JAVA is probably a bit easier than C++ for you.

Comment: Using Qt with C++ is quite easy for database tasks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to make dynamic websites with a programming language you should look into [`C#`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)

Comment: Can't see c# inside the question.